# How can I run the Linux software TkGate on Windows using Cygwin?

Tags: installation, cygwin, tcl, tk-toolkit

I need to use a program called [TkGate](https://sourceforge.net/projects/tkgate/) for some uni work, however it was made for Linux and only works on Windows if I can use [Cygwin](https://www.cygwin.com/).

I installed Cygwin, making sure to select the tcl and tk packages which are prerequisites for TkGate.

I then downloaded tkgate-1.8.5.tgz, and attempted to extract it to: C:\cygwin\home\Patrick\tkgate-1.8.5. However, I got this error message when doing so:

[image: Extraction error]

I decided to proceed with attempting to install the software anyway, so I launched the Cygwin terminal and cd to the folder. The README file said to run the configuration script ./configure, so I did this, however, I get a warning message saying that the tcl/tk components could not be located:

[image: Config error]

The README does go on to say:

> Normally the configuration will take place fully automatically , but
>   if    some components such as tcl/tk are in non-standard locations you
>   may need    to edit config.h and add the required directories to
>   TKGATE_INCDIRS and    TKGATE_LIBDIRS.

So I attempted to edit these values in the config.h file but it didn't make any difference. If someone could tell me where I have gone wrong it would be much appreciated.

EDIT: Okay, so I managed to unzip the tar.gz file and change the path variables in the config file so that config would run. However, now there are a lot of errors popping up when I run ./configure. Here is the output when I run it, including the configuration results:

```
$ ./configure
C compiler: gcc
Auto-configuring language to 'en' (LANG=en_US.UTF-8).
Tcl/Tk Version: 8.5
Configuring for Western language support.
Tcl script files found in: /usr/lib/tcl8.5
Tk script files found in: /usr/lib/tk8.5
bison found
which: no lex in (/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/cygdrive/c/Program Files/ImageMagick-6.9.3-Q16:/cygdrive/c/ProgramData/Oracle/Java/javapath:/cygdrive/c/Program Files/Common Files/Microsoft Shared/Windows Live:/cygdrive/c/Program Files (x86)/Common Files/Microsoft Shared/Windows Live:/cygdrive/c/Program Files (x86)/Intel/iCLS Client:/cygdrive/c/Program Files/Intel/iCLS Client:/cygdrive/c/Windows/system32:/cygdrive/c/Windows:/cygdrive/c/Windows/System32/Wbem:/cygdrive/c/Windows/System32/WindowsPowerShell/v1.0:/cygdrive/c/Program Files/Intel/Intel(R) Management Engine Components/DAL:/cygdrive/c/Program Files/Intel/Intel(R) Management Engine Components/IPT:/cygdrive/c/Program Files (x86)/Intel/Intel(R) Management Engine Components/DAL:/cygdrive/c/Program Files (x86)/Intel/Intel(R) Management Engine Components/IPT:/cygdrive/c/Program Files (x86)/EgisTec BioExcess/x64:/cygdrive/c/Program Files (x86)/EgisTec BioExcess:/cygdrive/c/Program Files (x86)/Windows Live/Shared:/cygdrive/c/Program Files (x86)/NVIDIA Corporation/PhysX/Common:/cygdrive/c/Program Files (x86)/Java/jre1.8.0_45/bin:/cygdrive/c/WINDOWS/system32:/cygdrive/c/WINDOWS:/cygdrive/c/WINDOWS/System32/Wbem:/cygdrive/c/WINDOWS/System32/WindowsPowerShell/v1.0:/cygdrive/c/Program Files (x86)/Windows Kits/8.1/Windows Performance Toolkit:/cygdrive/c/Program Files (x86)/GtkSharp/2.12/bin:/cygdrive/c/Program Files (x86)/Skype/Phone:/cygdrive/c/Program Files (x86)/Microsoft SQL Server/Client SDK/ODBC/130/Tools/Binn:/cygdrive/c/Program Files (x86)/Microsoft SQL Server/130/Tools/Binn:/cygdrive/c/Program Files (x86)/Microsoft SQL Server/130/DTS/Binn:/cygdrive/c/Program Files (x86)/Microsoft SQL Server/130/Tools/Binn/ManagementStudio:/cygdrive/c/WINDOWS/system32/config/systemprofile/.dnx/bin:/cygdrive/c/Program Files/Microsoft DNX/Dnvm:/cygdrive/c/Users/Patrick/AppData/Local/Microsoft/WindowsApps:/usr/lib/lapack)
flex found
lex test OK.
yyrestart found.
found X11/Xlib.h in: /usr/include
long long supported
getopt uses optreset.
WARNING: getopt does handle switches after file names.
*** updating config.h
tail: cannot open '+377' for reading: No such file or directory
*** doing xmkmf
In file included from ./Imakefile:19:0,
                 from /usr/lib/X11/config/Imake.tmpl:2194,
                 from Imakefile.c:15:
./config.h:385:0: error: #endif without #if
 #endif
 ^
./config.h:387:0: error: #endif without #if
 #endif
 ^
imake: Exit code 1.
  Stop.
In file included from ./Imakefile:2:0,
                 from /usr/lib/X11/config/Imake.tmpl:2194,
                 from Imakefile.c:15:
./../../config.h:385:0: error: #endif without #if
 #endif
 ^
./../../config.h:387:0: error: #endif without #if
 #endif
 ^
imake: Exit code 1.
  Stop.
In file included from ./Imakefile:18:0,
                 from /usr/lib/X11/config/Imake.tmpl:2194,
                 from Imakefile.c:15:
./../../config.h:385:0: error: #endif without #if
 #endif
 ^
./../../config.h:387:0: error: #endif without #if
 #endif
 ^
imake: Exit code 1.
  Stop.
In file included from ./Imakefile:2:0,
                 from /usr/lib/X11/config/Imake.tmpl:2194,
                 from Imakefile.c:15:
./../../config.h:385:0: error: #endif without #if
 #endif
 ^
./../../config.h:387:0: error: #endif without #if
 #endif
 ^
imake: Exit code 1.
  Stop.
In file included from ./Imakefile:18:0,
                 from /usr/lib/X11/config/Imake.tmpl:2194,
                 from Imakefile.c:15:
./../../config.h:385:0: error: #endif without #if
 #endif
 ^
./../../config.h:387:0: error: #endif without #if
 #endif
 ^
imake: Exit code 1.
  Stop.
*** doing includes
Makefile:8: *** missing separator.  Stop.
*** doing dependencies
Makefile:8: *** missing separator.  Stop.
*************************************************************
Configuration Results:
  Language Support: Western (English and European)
  C Compiler:       gcc
  Tcl/Tk Version:   8.5
  Library Path:      -L/usr/lib
  Include Path:      -I/usr/include
  Libraries:         -ltk8.5 -ltcl8.5 -lX11 -ldl -lm
  Primary Home:     /usr/X11R6/lib/tkgate-1.8.5
  Secondary Home:   /home/Patrick/build/tkgate-1.8.5
  optreset usage:   1
  long long usage:  1
  Ephemeral Signal: 1
  Use sigset:       0
  Yacc:             bison -y
  Lex:              flex -l
  No yyrestart:     0
*************************************************************
* Configuration complete - type 'make' to compile.
*************************************************************
```

And when I try to run the make command as it says to do, I get this message saying that there is something wrong on line 8 of the Makefile:

[image: Makefile error]

Comment: to extract use cygwin tar, not winrar. Have you installed the packages  `tcl-devel` and `tcl-tk-devel` ? How have you changed the `TKGATE_INCDIRS` and `TKGATE_LIBDIRS`variables ?

Comment: In the lib folder for cygwin I have tcl8.5 and tk8.5. Where should I extract to? What should I change the variables to?

Comment: The log say that tcl and tck are identified, but there is an error building config.h. You need to look the reasons of the errors

Comment: I have not  used Cygwin in years, but it appears to me from your output that you need to install some more packages needed to fully set up TkGate on your system. If possible, I would suggest the you install the MinGW and MSys systems instead of Cygwin, and learn how to work with Unix-ish operating systems. (Thats something really too complex to address on this site; There's lots of web pages out there to help you get started, though..)